subDocument array in mongoose is typeof object
I am new to mongoose and building an ecommerce. the cart schema looks like this.
import { model, Schema } from "mongoose";
import { Product } from "./product.model.js";

const ProductSchema = new Schema({
  prod_id: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Product",
  },
  quantity: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
});

const cartSchema = new Schema(
  {
    cart_products: {
      type: [ProductSchema],
      default: [],
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

export const Cart = model("Cart", cartSchema);


in a new controller i am taking in an array and iterating over it to update the cart_products array if a product exist or add if not already exists.
const updateCart = async (req, res, _next) => {
  try {
    const new_cart_prods = req.body;
    const { cart_id } = req.query;

    // Validate request body
    if (!Array.isArray(new_cart_prods) || new_cart_prods.length === 0) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: "Bad Request",
        message: "Invalid or empty request body",
      });
    }

    const cart = await Cart.find({ _id: cart_id });
    console.log(cart, "-------0");
    console.log(typeof cart.cart_products, "-------1");
    console.log(cart.cart_products, "----2");

    // Update cart products
    const updated_prods = await Promise.all(
      new_cart_prods.map(async (new_prod) => {
        const filter = {
          _id: cart_id,
          "cart_products.prod_id": new_prod.prod_id,
        };
        const result = await Cart.findOneAndUpdate(
          filter,
          {
            $push: {
              cart_products: {
                prod_id: new_prod.prod_id,
                quantity: new_prod.quantity,
              },
            },
          },
          { new: true, upsert: true }
        );
        console.log(result, "result");
        return result;
      })
    );
    console.log(updated_prods, "updated_prods");
    if (updated_prods.length === 0) {
      return res.status(500).json({
        error: "Internal Server Error",
        message: "Failed to update cart",
      });
    }

    // Send success response
    return res.status(200).json({
      message: "Cart updated successfully",
      // updated_prods,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error updating cart:", error);
    return res.status(500).json({
      error: "Internal Server Error",
      message: "An unexpected error occurred",
    });
  }
};


but i get an error: Error updating cart: MongoServerError: Plan executor error during findAndModify :: caused by :: The field 'cart_products' must be an array but is of type object in document {_id: ObjectId('666b2f35448c581ecb44d40d')}
i tried checking the typeof which gave the value object and also Array.isArray() which gave true which is damn confusing

You are using upsert: true option so if a document does not match your filter of {_id: cart_id, "cart_products.prod_id": new_prod.prod_id} then mongoose will try to add a brand new document. Your $push then becomes invalid. You need to rethink your control flow.

$push on an nonexistent field will create an array, that part is fine.  The error indicates that some document that is already in the database has a non-array object in that field, and you can't push to an object.  Note that the error gave you the _id of the offending document, go look it up in the database using the she..

@Joe. Op is doing a findOneAndUpdate using _id AND cart_products.prod_id condition. If mongoose finds a document the $push will work. If it doesn't find based on both conditions it will create a new document because upsert: true is set.  A  findAndModify error will be thrown because the cart_products is then being interpreted as an object, the $push is ignored.

That offending _id is a red herring because mongoose will use the _id given in the findOneAndUpdate first argument filter object to create a new document but there already exists a document with that _id so it won't work anyway. A findOneAndUpdate based on _id with upsert: true almost never works because by definition you are looking based on _id so you won't be able to add another document with the same _id. If $push is removed OP would get  a E11000 duplicate key error

Thanks guys now that i reRead the code I think what is wrong is that the filter brings back me a specific product that exist in cart which obviously is a object hence I just cannot apply a array function.
